# Heroku- 502 while accessing URL/info/refs, when doing "git push heroku master"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to push a git repository to heroku, but am getting an error when doing the push.  The error message is

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 502 while accessing http://powerful-castle-9664.herokuapp.com/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I'm confused because that URL it listed is actually clickable, and takes me to a standard Heroku landing page, not any sort of error listing.

I think there error has something to do with the fact that I originally made this heroku remote, then ended up deleting it (through the online interface) and reinitializing it.  Suspect that Heroku is getting confused where I want to push, but I can't figure out where.  This is also just a theory, I could be totally wrong.

I'm sure a lot more information will be needed, so just ask and I'll provide.  Some info I have now.

running `git remote` returns

```
heroku
origin
```

The contents of my git config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku.com:powerful-castle-9664.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://powerful-castle-9664.herokuapp.com/
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Not sure what else to provide.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the correct address of your app?  If you deleted the app on Heroku and made a new one it will not have the same address. Check your heroku dashboard to see the new address.

https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps

You'll have to update your remote to reflect the new address as well.